# How to Wrap WildCard before search criteria in meta_query wordpress?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

if you see below code when we pass these args  in WP_QUERY  it will generate a query that will wrap % around test 
Something like this

```
 " AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%test%') ) "
```

is there any possibility i want to have only % at start of 'test' string ?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
          'key' => 'geo_address',
          'value' => 'test',
          'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
    )

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that, because `wp_query` adds %..% authomatically. However, you can do that with custom query like;

```
global $wpdb;

$specific_posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE 
post_type='job_listing' AND post_status ='publish' AND ID
 IN(
SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key='geo_address' 
AND meta_value LIKE '%test'
) ORDER BY post_date DESC");
```

**Edit:** If you don't want to do that with custom query, you need to use [posts_where](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) action of wp like;

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'custom_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function custom_posts_where( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $custom_post_meta_value = $wp_query->get( 'custom_value' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_key = "geo_address" AND ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_value LIKE \'' . esc_sql( like_escape( $custom_post_meta_value ) ) . '\'';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

And in your query, use it like below;

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
          'key' => 'geo_address',
          'custom_value' => '%test',
          'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
    )

);
```

Comment: I dont want to use custom query cuz there are many conditions i am  using in args .. i have to find way through this only

Comment: @Huseyin, there are some syntax errors in your WHERE clause. You need to enclose your $where .= line between double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Hrere is another solution  i think ill try both

```
function filter_meta_query( $pieces ) {

    if ( !empty( $pieces['where'] ) ) {
        $pieces['where'] = preg_replace( '/(.*?)LIKE \'\%(.*?)\%\'/', "\$1LIKE '\$2%'", $pieces['where'] );
    }

    return $pieces;
}


add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', 'filter_meta_query' );

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'any_key',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' => '%test'
        )
    )
);

// the query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// remove it after the query.
remove_filter( 'get_meta_sql', 'filter_meta_query' );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem this post solve the problem with using REGEX instead of LIKE :
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159426/meta-query-with-string-starting-like-pattern