# In WordPress, get all posts having keyword in Title, Tag or Category?

Tags: php, wordpress

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613287/wordpress-get-posts-if-keyword-exists-in-title-content-or-tag), but it's now 7 years old, so I thought I'd ask again.

I'm using the **get_posts()** function but it seems that whatever is passed as the 's' parameter is only matched against the post title. For example, this code only returns posts containing 'sunflower' in the title, not posts containing 'sunflower' in one of their tags

```
$args = array(  'numberposts' => 99,  's' => 'sunflower'); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

I'm just starting out with WP development, so maybe I'm overlooking something or using the wrong function... Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO this is much more complicated than it should be, but I managed to get what I want with the following code:

```
$searchTerm =  trim($_REQUEST['search']);

// Get all slugs that are a partial match in tags
$matching_terms_tags = get_terms( array(  'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',  'fields' => 'slugs', 'name__like' => $searchTerm ) );

// Get all slugs that are a partial match in categories
$matching_terms_categories = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'category',  'fields' => 'slugs', 'name__like' => $searchTerm ) );                       

// Build taxonomy query 
$argsTax = array('numberposts' => 999, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'nopaging' => true);
$argsTax['tax_query'] = array 
        (
            array
            (
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array ('taxonomy' => 'category', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms'    => $matching_terms_categories,'operator' => 'IN',),
                array ('taxonomy' => 'post_tag', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms'    => $matching_terms_tags, 'operator' => 'IN', ),
            ),
        );            

// Get all posts with matching tags and/or matching categories
$postsTax = get_posts($argsTax);

// Also get all posts matching the term, using the regular WP argument 's'
$argsTerms = array('numberposts' => 999, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'nopaging' => true, 's' => $searchTerm);
$postsSearch = get_posts($argsTerms);

// Merge the 2 result sets and remove duplicates            
$postsAll = array_merge($postsSearch, $postsTax);            
$postAllNoDupes = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $postsAll)));

foreach ($postAllNoDupes as $post)
{
    echo get_the_title($post);
}

wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 1):

To additionally get posts with 'sunflower' as a tag you need to add taxonomy parameters like so:

```
$args = [
'numberposts' => 99,
's' => 'sunflower',
'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'   => 'slug',
            'terms'   => 'sunflower'
        ]
    ]
]; 

$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

Official docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Comment: Thanks @Tami this helps! I'm sorry I should have mentioned that I'm trying to partial match those fields... So if someone searches for 'sunflo', I'd like to get all posts with that string in the title, tags or category: for example, all posts tagged with 'sunflower'. Again sorry if I'm unclear, English is my second language. Thanks much!

Comment: Check this out, it might have what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192642/how-to-wrap-wildcard-before-search-criteria-in-meta-query-wordpress otherwise you'll have to look into a plugin that does partial word search